# Ruby on Rails: Add a relationship between two scaffolds (CD's and cd_tracks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I'm a new RoR dev and I've created a practice catalogue web page that allow's entries for CD's, DVD's and books. Im trying to make a new scaffold(cd_track) that would allow for a user to input tracks into their CD catalogue. I thought i could just add a column but now I need to create a new scaffold to allow for this functionality because 1 CD can have multiple tracks. Im confused on relationships between scaffolds and wondering if this is even possible? Could i create the two scaffold and connect them to allow for the CD scaffold to have multiple tracks listed under each CD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a one-to-many (1:N) relationship and you can achieve this like so:

```sh
rails g scaffold parent_model
rails g scaffold child_model parent_model:references

# or in your case:
rails g scaffold cd 
rails g scaffold cd_track cd:references
```

the above allows for an instance of cd to have multiple cd_tracks. A single cd_track now **needs** a cd_id in order to be valid (and save to db).

in your model you should have

```rb
# models/cd.rb
class Cd 
  has_many :cd_tracks
end

# models/cd_track.rb
class CdTracks
  belongs_to :cd
end
```

more generally just adding the reference afterwards is also fine:

```sh
rails g migration AddCdToCdTracks cd:references
rails db:migrate
```

You can test this in `rails console`:

```rb
cd = Cd.create
cd_track = CdTrack.create(cd: cd)
cd_track.cd == cd #=> true
cd.cd_tracks.first == cd_track #=> true
```

Comment: awesome thank you for the assist! i see im getting a NoMethodError saying my ID = nil. But i think i can mess around to fix that! thanks again

Comment: any existing cd_tracks should throw an error now because the foreign_key (cd_id) is nil.